# KeyError after resampling

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes df indexed by Datetime and df2 which has column Date (Series).

Before resampling I can run:

```
>>>> df[df2['Date'][0]]
```

and obtain all rows corresponding to day df2['Date'][0] which is 2013-08-07 in this example. However after resampling by day I can no longer obtain the row corresponding to that day as:

```
>>>> df.resample('D', how=np.max)[df2['Date'][0]]    
KeyError: u'no item named 2013-08-07'
```

although that day is in the dataset

```
>>>> df.resample('D', how=np.max).head()
            | Temp  | etc
Date        |       |
---------------------------
2013-08-07  | 26.1  |
---------------------------
2013-08-08  | 28.2  |
---------------------------
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is a bug or it is designed to be like this, or, if the latter is true, why. But you can do this to get the desired result:

```
In [168]:

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(100), columns=['Temp'])
df1.index=pd.date_range('2013-08-07',periods=100,freq='5H')
df1.index.name='Date'

In [169]:

df2=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2013-08-07',periods=23, freq='D'), columns=['Date'])

In [170]:
#You can do this
df3=df1.resample('D', how=np.max)
print df3[df3.index==df2['Date'][0]]
              Temp
Date              
2013-08-07  0.8128

[1 rows x 1 columns]

In [171]:
df3[df2['Date'][0]]
#Error
```